# Facebook posting/sharing a link With image

Tags: android, facebook

The posting is possible using the developer account only etc... For other accounts:

`{"error":{"message":"(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action","type":"OAuthException","code":200}}` etc...

This is the response showing when trying to post/share a link to fb...

Here is my fb posting code:

```
public void facebook_post() {

    nProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);

    nFacebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);

    SessionStore.restore(nFacebook, this);

    AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncFbRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(nFacebook);

    Bundle params = new Bundle();

    params.putString("message", " ");

    params.putString("name", "");
    params.putString("caption", " ");
    params.putString("link",
            "");
    params.putString("description",
            "");
    params.putString("picture",
            "");

    mAsyncFbRunner.request("me/feed", params, "POST",
            new WallPostListener(), null);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to new facebook policy, you need to submit your app for review if you are publishing anything. after facebook approval you can upload picture by using any login. you can check this link for review process

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/

https://github.com/sauce/guide/wiki/Facebook's-approval-process